# Screen reader not reading Icon in Firefox / NVDA but can be read on chrome

Tags: html, reactjs, accessibility

I have an icon that is being skipped by a screen reader and is being read as "blank" in firefox / NVDA. It can be read on chrome and I'm using a screen reader on my mac.

```html
<Icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="icon" tabindex={0} />
```

I was wondering what I overlooked or what I can do to solve the problem. Any insight would help! :)

I tried `aria-hidden="false"` `aria-label='icon'` `tabindex={0}` to make it tababble. But for some reason it won't be read on firefox / NVDA

Comment: I assume you mean NVDA (the free screenreader for Windows)? NVIDIA is a graphics card manufacturer :-)

Comment: how do you mean, "skipped"? We need to see your React component or (probably better) the HTML it produces.

Comment: `<ToolTip title={toolTip} aria-label='tooltip'>
<InfoIcon className={styles.tooltipIcon} aria-hidden='false' aria-label='icon' />
<ToolTip/>`

Comment: Is the `<icon>` element a custom element? If so, what's it a subclass of? The code in your comment uses `<infoicon>`, which I presume is another custom element? How are you navigating with NVDA? Down arrow? TAB? Navigation shortcut key such as `g`?

Comment: Custom element names must contain hyphens. (: According to the tags, this is a react component. @JoshuaBautista please share the rendered HTML. You know that _icon_ as an accessible name is not at all useful, right?

Comment: <InfoIcon /> is coming from `@material-ui/icons/Info`

Comment: This is the rendered HTML

`<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root xyz_tooltipIcon_uWLI8" focusable='false' viewBox='0 0 24 24' aria-hidden='false' aria-label='More Information Icon' tabindex='0'>
 <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12S4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2ZM1 15H-2V-6H2V6ZM0-8H-2V7h2v2z"></path>
</svg>`

Comment: Just remove aria-hidden="false". It's totally useless, and mistaken as aria-hidden="true" by some screen readers.